# "Add to cart" feature doesn't work in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, opencart2.x

I have changed value of my select option in OpenCart 2.x

From this:

```
<option value="12">TEST</option>
```

To this:

```
<option value="TEST">TEST</option>
```

But after I changed it the selection is not adding to cart. It looks like the JavaScript that is adding options into the cart doesn't see it.

I have found the code which is adding options to the cart:

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
```

Any ideas how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is that option a required or an optional option?

Comment: it is required option